# Nativescript Angular cannot find module "nativescript-angular/forms"

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am going through a tutorial that requires an import from "nativescript-angular/forms" for binding but I am getting an error that says

> Cannot find module 'nativescript-angular/forms' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

`import { NativeScriptFormsModule } from 'nativescript-angular/forms';`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Nativescript 7, the imports for Angular related modules are updated to `@nativescript/angular`. The updated version of your code should look something like:

```js
import { NativeScriptFormsModule } from '@nativescript/angular';
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because a lot of the imports has been changed since NativeScript 8, not just Angular related modules.

You can solve it by replacing the imports that you have in your code with:

```
import { NativeScriptFormsModule } from '@nativescript/angular';
```

Or

- Just delete it, then reimport it by deleting and rewriting the last character of the class name, or just use the shortcuts defined on your IDE.
- if you are installing the needed module, you will get a suggestion just where you used that class.
  this is a silly solution, but I use it all the time, it's going to save you a lot of time, so you don't have to look at the right imports on the internet.